# How to get Twitter status with JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

I found about JQuery jsonp issues in [jQuery ajax (jsonp) ignores a timeout and doesn’t fire the error event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002367/jquery-ajax-jsonp-ignores-a-timeout-and-doesnt-fire-the-error-event).

I have tried to get my last twitter updates with:

```
var jsonTwitterFeed = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/softamo.json?count=3";

$.jsonp({
        url: jsonTwitterFeed,
        data: {},
        dataType: "jsonp",
        callbackParameter: "jsoncallback",
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(){
                $("#sNews ul.tweets").append("<li>" + replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(data.text) + "</li>");                
            });            

        },
        error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("ERREUR: " + textStatus);
            alert("ERREUR: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });

function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
}
```

The error alert calls execute with:

> ERREUR: error
>   ERREUR: undefined

However, I can see the JSON Object in Firebug.

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: @Sergio: see updated answer with working page... (at least for me)

Comment: Appending "&callback=?" was enough for me to get it working; didn't need data, dataType or callbackParameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is entirely relevant but you might have been missing the callback for JSONP in your feed URL unless it's set by default:

```
var jsonTwitterFeed = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/softamo.json?count=3&callback=?";
```

Also, your jquery AJAX call can simply use the default AJAX and not JSONP.  Try this and let us know:

```
$.ajax({
        url: jsonTwitterFeed,
        data: {},
        dataType: "jsonp",
        callbackParameter: "jsoncallback",
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data){
            var str = '';
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
                str += '<li>' + replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(data[i].text) + '</li>';
            }
            $("#sNews ul.tweets").append(str);
        },
        error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("ERREUR: " + textStatus);
            alert("ERREUR: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });

function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
}
```

Comment: &callback=? is not necessar. 

Replace the code insde success with the next code and I will accept your answer. 

for(var i = 0; i  < data.length; i++) {
$("#sNews ul.tweets").append("<li>" + replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(data[i].text) + "</li>");
}

Comment: @sergio, code updated and I also made a speed improvement to your loop.  It avoids multiple DOM lookups until it's absolutely necessary to append the string after all tweets were found and the HTML has been generated.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
 $.each(data, function(){
    $("#sNews ul.tweets").append("<li>" + replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(data.text) + "</li>");
```

to

```
$.each(data, function(post, val){
   $("#sNews ul.tweets").append("<li>" + replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(val.text) + "</li>");
```

**Edit**:

I did change one other thing but forgot to add it to the answer.

```
callbackParameter: "jsoncallback",
```

should be

```
callbackParameter: "callback",
```

Just for completeness here is a test page I did that works:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>test</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jsonp-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready( function() {
         var jsonTwitterFeed = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/dougw.json?count=3";

         $.jsonp({
            url: jsonTwitterFeed,
            data: {},
            dataType: "jsonp",
            callbackParameter: "callback",
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data){
               $.each(data, function(key, val){
                  $("#sNews ul.tweets").append("<li>" + replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(val.text) + "</li>");                
             });            
         },
         error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
             alert("ERREUR: " + textStatus);
             alert("ERREUR: " + errorThrown);
         }
     });
         function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
            var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
            return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
         }
      });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="sNews">
      <ul class="tweets">
      </ul>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does not change anything. I think the success code does not execute at all.

Comment: @Sergio, sorry I forgot one of the changes I made to make it work... see edit in answer.  \Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the following code, and got the success function to fire correctly.

```
$.getJSON(jsonTwitterFeed, {
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function(){
            $("#sNews ul.tweets").append("<li>" + replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(data.text) + "</li>");                
        });            

    },
    error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("ERREUR: " + textStatus);
        alert("ERREUR: " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: I get the next error with your suggestion: object is undefined
script.appendChild(document.createTextNo...(object[name],args)===false)break;}else\n