# jQuery: How to enable `timeout` for `$.ajax({dataType:'jsonp'...`? Is there any solution?

Tags: ajax, jquery, timeout, jsonp

jQuery: How to enable `timeout` for `$.ajax({dataType:'jsonp'...`? Is there any solution? http://jsfiddle.net/laukstein/2wcpU/4

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:'http://lab.laukstein.com/ajax-seo/.json',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    timeout:200, // Not working with dataType:'jsonp'
    success:function(data){$('#content').html(data.content);},
    error:function(request,status,error){$('#content').html('request failed');}
});
```

I do not like to use some plugins for that, like http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002367/jquery-ajax-jsonp-ignores-a-timeout-and-doesnt-fire-the-error-event

Comment: I would not like to use some plugins for that, like http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at the plugins code and see what it does, however the answer I linked to states that it is a limitation of JSONP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my solution with `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` http://jsfiddle.net/laukstein/2wcpU/7/

```
$('#content').ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).html('Loading...');
});
var timer=window.setTimeout(function(){
    $('#content').html('Loading seems to be taking a while. Try again.');
},2000);
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:'http://lab.laukstein.com/ajax-seo/.json',
    dataType:'jsonp',
    success:function(data){
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
        $('#content').html(data.content);
    },
    error:function(){
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
        $('#content').html('The request failed. Try to refresh page.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Binyamin,

this SO answer should help you:

[jQuery ajax (jsonp) ignores a timeout and doesn't fire the error event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002367/jquery-ajax-jsonp-ignores-a-timeout-and-doesnt-fire-the-error-event)

basically, suggests using `jquery.jsonp` instead of $ajax

Comment: That's an exact duplicate of the question the same question linked to in my comment on the question.

Comment: sorry marcus, can see that now. comment wasn't there as i started my answer :)

Comment: I seen that answers already before. Unfortunately I would not like to use some plugins for that like http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/. So I'm looking for some other solution?

Comment: Not a problem, but it probably shouldn't be listed as an answer to the question, but as a comment.