# Check if youtube video id exists Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, youtube, response

I am having the following code where realurl = 'TOwd30wXc-0' (youtube video ID):

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+realurl+"?v=2&alt=json-in-script",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) { PreviewVideo(data) }
    });
```

Where PreviewVideo(data) is the function that parses json response and does other things with it.

My problem is, if video ID is incorrect (doesn't exist), I am not receiving any notice about that. I have tried adding `error: function() { alert('error occured') }` into $.ajax but it simply does nothing.

Does anybody know a way how to determine if video is okay or not? If video exists, call PreviewVideo(data), else - call VideoError() ?

**EDIT:** If I put invalid ID, im getting

```
GET http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/TOwd30wXc-?v=2&alt=json-in-script&callback=jQuery17205096300751902163_1353530502856&_=1353530692237 400 (Bad Request)
```

in the javascript console (Chrome)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you maybe provide both a valid and invalid value for `realurl` so we can see what's supposed to be returned from the API?

Comment: How abt if(data != null){PreviewVideo(data)}  .. The error function is only called if there was an error with the request or the response.. Otherwise it will hit the success callback

Comment: I have tried the following:

success: function (data) {
                if(data != null) { PreviewVideo(data) }
                else { alert('invalid'); }
            }

but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

According to [the jQuery forums](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/catching-a-jsonp-error), you cannot catch bad requests. That is to say, `statusCode` or `error` parameters won't help (which makes sense given it's really supposed to call a per-determined function name on success).

<strike>However, there is a work-around present by using the deferred object interface, [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/DEfbL/) *(Provided by [Kevin B](http://forum.jquery.com/user/kevin-b) on jQuery forums)*</strike>

I take it back, thought it is solvable using a timeout whih appears to be the [best solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4924957/298053) on a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924434/catching-a-jsonp-error-on-a-cross-domain-request).