# IMDb XML error catch, jQuery.type not returning anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, json

I'm trying to catch errors/no results in my IMDb AJAX call.

The code gets matching title results to the search term in JSONP to override the same-origin policy.
I'm working off this tutorial:
[Does IMDB provide an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api)

When there is no result, IMDb sends an XML error and I'm trying to catch it and alert('ERROR').

Here is the code:

```
function searchDatabase() {

    var searchTerm = document.getElementById('search').value;
    var firstLetter = searchTerm.charAt(0);
    var resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');

    $('#result').empty();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://sg.media-imdb.com/suggests/' +firstLetter+ '/' +searchTerm+ '.json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'imdb$'+searchTerm,
        statusCode: {
            403: function() {
                alert('HTTP ERROR');
            }
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        if(jQuery.type(response) !== "object") {
                alert('ERROR');
            } else {
            alert(jQuery.type(response));
                for(var x in response["d"]) {
                resultDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br/>' +response["d"][x]["l"]+ '<br/>');
            }
        }
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('ERROR');
    });

}
```

First of all, what datatype is XML? I'm still very new to JSON and XML, and I think I understand that JSON is an object? I've read somewhere else that JSON is not an object (as compared to Javascript object literal).

jQuery.type returns 'string', 'array', etc. and it returns everything else as 'object.
When the search term (e.g. "some") successfully returns a result, it's in JSON so the alert goes off for `if(jQuery.type(response) === 'object' { alert('OBJECT!'); }` but when a search term is invalid (e.g. "something") it doesn't return anything at all and just shows HTTP code 403 in console.

I've also tried catching the HTTP code in the AJAX call following the instructions for "statusCode" from here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ but it doesn't do anything.

Am I missing a very simple alternative way to catch the error? I'm afraid I'm just being a novice, I just started learning about JSON and XML 3 days ago. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know no one's answered but I figured it out a few days after I asked the question and hopefully others looking for the same answer will find this useful.
I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924434/catching-a-jsonp-error-on-a-cross-domain-request) which explains you cannot use the $.ajax 'error' key to catch errors when making JSONP calls (cross-domain). This is the only way I've found so far that works, to log the error with setTimeout.