# handle google alert via jQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, json, jsonp

I'm trying to parse the RSS feed generated by Google alerts via jQuery. I can get the XHR request to return XML via a JSON-P however i'm struggling to parse the response.

Then Firebug console throws the following error:

```
missing ; before statement
<?xml version="1.0"?><feed xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:gr=...
```

From what I've read this is because the response is being evaluated as `script` and not `xml`, but i could be wrong!

I've tried to implement the following solutions from related questions:

[jQuery ajax request using jsonp error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247295/jquery-ajax-request-using-jsonp-error)

[jQuery XML parsing with namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces)

and this trick sheet:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/wiki/TipsAndTricks

Create a google alerts feed here: http://www.google.com/alerts

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>google alerts....</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Google alerts</h1>
    <div></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
jQuery(function() { 

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "GOOGLE ALERT FEED URL",
        dataType: "jsonp xml"
    }).done(function(data) {

        console.log(data);  
    }).fail(function(jq_xhr, text_status) {

        console.log("Error: " + text_status);
    });
});
-->
</script>
```

Any advice would be appreciated, Cheers.

Comment: dataType should be dataType: "jsonp"