# How to retrieve error message from xOptions in jquery-jsonp library

Tags: json, jquery, jsonp

I am using the 2.3.1.min version of the **jquery-jsonp** library found here: https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp and it works as expected, namely the error function fires when an error occurs.  However, I cannot to seem to display the error encountered.  I checked the docs on github project but could not find an answer.

Is this a limitation?  Or am I not calling the right object?

My implementation..

The url parameter below is set to return a 404 page on purpose. Chrome dev tools shows a 404 response, but I cannot seem to capture that result..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jsonp({
                url: 'http://apps.mydomain.com/Service/NonExistant?&max=4&format=json',
                callbackParameter: "callback",
                error: function(xOptions, textStatus){ 
                    // this lines returns "error"
                    console.log(textStatus); 

                    // this returns the Object (but expanding it reveals no indication of error code / message)
                    console.log(xOptions);
                },
                success: function(json, textStatus) {
                    Populate(json); // this works fine
                }
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, you can't.  [Johnny Wey](http://johnnywey.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/jsonp-how-does-it-work/) explains it far better than I could - but essentially, it's relying on a "script" tag to get the JSON response, rather than a request executed via javascript.

You could wrap the type of error within the JSONP response per [Parsing JSONP Response in Javascript when 4xx or 5xx Http Error Code is Present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334413/parsing-jsonp-response-in-javascript-when-4xx-or-5xx-http-error-code-is-present), but that still won't help you with a 404 error.

Unfortunately, though JSONP error handling is effectively non-existent.  The "Cautionary Note" from [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/?ca=dgr-jw64JSONP-jQuery&S_TACT=105AGY46&S_CMP=grsitejw64) specifically mentions that "First and foremost, there is no error handling for JSONP calls".