# Is there any way to do cross-domain request from javascript and access the type of error response(401, 404, etc.) that it might generate

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I tried using jquery.ajax but it fails silently whenever there is an error response

Comment: did you set the `error` function to handle errors?

Comment: Yeah, the `error` callback should have this information. Show the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible without any workaround.

When making cross-domain (JSONP) requests, jQuery doesn't trigger an error event, [see this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309953/how-do-i-catch-jquery-getjson-or-ajax-with-datatype-set-to-jsonp-error-w/310084#310084).

If it's sufficient for you to know that there was an error (without getting additional info), you could try [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538745/how-to-tell-if-a-script-tag-failed-to-load/6948101#6948101), combined with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6132828/1350193).

If you really need the HTTP status code, you will have to work server-side, i.e. use your own server as a proxy to get the cross-domain resource. Then you can send additional info to JS using the JSONP callback; [see this solution on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5334413/parsing-jsonp-response-in-javascript-when-4xx-or-5xx-http-error-code-is-present/5666506#5666506).

Sorry for posting so many links, but I guess that's better than quotations... ;)