# Why do I keep getting an "undefined" error with this JSONP feed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jsonp, undefined

I am using the following code to retrieve data in JSONP format. I need to use it so if no data is returned, I can flag the error. I was using jQuery's ajax(), but it always returns 404 pages as being successful, so I need to use the [jquery-jsonp](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/) jQuery plug-in on Google Code for error handling.

I borrowed the code from the example on [jQuery ajax (jsonp) ignores a timeout and doesn't fire the error event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002367/jquery-ajax-jsonp-ignores-a-timeout-and-doesnt-fire-the-error-event), but I cannot seem to get it to work with my JSON, which is being sent as the MIME type "application/json" from the other server.

```
$(function(){
    var jsonFeed = "http://othersite.com/feed.json";

    $.jsonp({
        url: jsonFeed,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
                console.log("Title: " + item.title);

                if (i == 9) return false;
            });
        },
        error: function(XHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log("Error Status: " + textStatus);
            console.log("Error Thrown: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is an example of my JSON:

> [     {       "title"         : "My Title"    } ]

Can anyone spot the problem?

Comment: What you have shown as response from the server is JSON, not JSONP. For JSONP it should look like this: `methodName([{"title":"My Title"}])` where `methodName` must be passed as argument. For this the server must support this protocol. Are you sure that the remote server supports it?

Comment: What you described is the problem I'm having. I'm using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feed-json/ and wasn't adding the ?callback=methodName. Now, how do I take that and do something with the data in the each() above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure "othersite.com" actually supports JSONP. JSON cannot be converted to JSONP by the client. The server needs to support it be wrapping the content with a callback function.

Comment: Yes, I am using the WordPress plug-in Feed JSON: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feed-json/

Comment: I think this is the problem (not using callback=). Now how do I retrieve item.title since the data is wrapped in callback()?

Comment: You don't need to worry about retrieving that data. jQuery should be able to handle that for you and just give you the data.

Comment: I added &callback=callback, but now it's returning the same undefined error as well as "callback" is not defined. Any ideas?

Comment: callback=? not callback=callback. jQuery documentation states that it will replace the "?" in the url with its callback name.