# jquery autocomplete jsonp issues

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, jquery-autocomplete

So I've been through an interesting learning experience. The end product produces this...
No matter how hard I try I can not get the autocomplete to kick in ....
I type in DELTA in the #air input field, it makes the request
I get back a 200 on the response but then what?
What am I missing here...
Incidentally to me this looks like a simple Json response and not a JsonP response but for some reason when I send the request as Json I get a 401 error however just changing it to JsonP I get back the 200 responses.

Can someone help me comprehend why I can't get the dropdown to show the airline names (and record the selected airline code

Thanks...

```
[
  {
    "id": "DL",
    "label": "DELTA AIRLINES"
  },
  {
    "id": "GG",
    "label": "Delta Airlines (Group Space)"
  }
]
```

To get it I do this...

```
$(function() {

var url="http://<<ourinternalserver>>.com/scripts/broker.dll?_program=tas.json_airlines_test.sas";


$( "#air" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        term: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) {
            console.log('success');
      } // end of success
    }); // end of ajax
  },
  minLength: 2

 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `timeout parameter` in [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) like,

```
var req = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {
      term: request.term
    },
    timeout : 10000
}); // end of ajax

req.success(function() {
    console.log('Success!');
});

req.error(function() {
    console.log('Error!');
});
```

Read [jquery jsonp-requests](http://www.haykranen.nl/2011/02/25/jquery-1-5-and-jsonp-requests/) and [Autocomplete jsonp](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) and [jQuery ajax (jsonp) ignores a timeout and doesn't fire the error event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002367/jquery-ajax-jsonp-ignores-a-timeout-and-doesnt-fire-the-error-event)